# Delete settings file from GitHub repo without deleting it from every remote clone

Tags: php, git, github

I've inherited a PHP Weather Template Website that's updated and distributed through GitHub. The previous owner did not make a sufficient .gitignore file in the beginning, so there are a number of files that are tracked by git that shouldn't. These files include .csv databases that are updated with users' data, json data files, and a settings.php file. After adding a list of files to the .gitignore, my issue now is the best way to get these files to not be tracked by git on all of the remote clones that users are using. My first thought was to just do a `git rm --cached <files>`, however that removes the files from everyone, deleting everyone's data.

Next I thought to warn people to backup the files and in a week I'd issue the `git rm --cached` command, however with an unknown but fairly large number of users, I have no guarantee that everyone will see the message in the forums before its too late, plus surely some users will do a `git pull` without even looking at the forums.

For the same reasons as above, having each user issue `git rm --cached` probably won't work either.

Ultimately, is there any way that I can get git to stop tracking these files on every remote copy of the template, without relying on any user interaction. A simple delete-from-GitHub-but-not-from-outstanding-copies command would be great.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do what you want. Github is not a file hosting, it's git repository hosting, it shows the content of your repositories. To remove files from Github you have to remove the files from repository (not necessary in that order: you can remove files directly from Github using web interface but then you'll have to pull changes and the files will be removed in your local repo). No way around that, sorry.

Comment: I figured it was a long shot, just trying to use what I was given. Any decent way to distribute a website template that's actively being developed with something simple for users to do to update like `git pull`, and so it won't try to overwrite settings and data files with each update?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want to remove the .csv files from the repository, but when someone else does a `git pull` their own .csv's are unaffected.

Quick Note: Do this in a separate branch or a dry run to be safe.

1) untrack all files `git rm -r --cached .`

2) update the .gitignore file to include all of these files.

3) add all the files back `git add .` (this will not include .gitignored files)

4) commit/push

Comment: Nope. Doing this is the same as using `git rm -r --cached <files>` and listing each file. Result is the files in the `.gitignore` being deleted on remote clones. And if the user does a `git stash` beforehand, they still each have to do a `git rm -r --cached <files>` to get git back to a clean status.